# Reference a cell by name in Excel.Application in ASP

Tags: excel, asp-classic

How do I reference a cell by name rather than Row,Col?

Currently, I have the following code:

```
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sPathToTemplate)

oExcel.Cells(1,1).Value = strShippingName
```

But rather than referring to the shipping name as "1,1", I'd like to refer to it by it's name, "shipping_name"

But this obviously doesn't work:

```
oExcel.Cells("shipping_name").Value
```

Any ideas? I can't seem to find any documentation on Excel.Application in any of my books... If anyone knows any online stuff that would be nice too.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Excel? 2003?

Comment: Well, I've got 2007 running on my local testing server on my PC, but I think it will be 2003 on the end-use server.  Anyway to account for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
oExcel.Range("shipping_name").Value = strShippingName
```